# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

When I am taking the `AuthentiationManager` object in the "filter chain" method the code works properly and I don't know why. Is it somehow the authentication manager bean has been created twice? If so, How to resolve it?

This is my `SecurityConfig` class:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.Jahedullah")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig{
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;

    public SecurityConfig(ApplicationUserService applicationUserService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.applicationUserService = applicationUserService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    // This Bean is Used when you are using CustomUserDetailsService -> which is used to fetch user Id and Pass and other info from DB.
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);

        return  provider;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(http)))
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/Products/**").hasAuthority(PRODUCT_WRITE.getPermission())
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/Products/**").hasAuthority(PRODUCT_WRITE.getPermission())
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/Products/**").hasAuthority(PRODUCT_WRITE.getPermission())
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/Products/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), USER.name())
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
            .csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The error that is showing me is given below. Can someone explain me what is going on under the hood? Where is exactly the two beans are being instantiated?

```
2023-01-03 22:46:27.764  INFO 2300 --- [           main] com.Jahedullah.ProjectV1.Tech_Box        : Starting Tech_Box using Java 1.8.0_352 on Jahedul with PID 2300 (C:\Users\comm\IdeaProjects\MVC-Product_CRUD-ProjectV1\target\classes started by comm in C:\Users\comm\IdeaProjects\MVC-Product_CRUD-ProjectV1)
2023-01-03 22:46:27.771  INFO 2300 --- [           main] com.Jahedullah.ProjectV1.Tech_Box        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-03 22:46:30.477  INFO 2300 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
2023-01-03 22:46:30.493  INFO 2300 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-03 22:46:30.494  INFO 2300 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2023-01-03 22:46:30.690  INFO 2300 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/ProjectV1]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-03 22:46:30.690  INFO 2300 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2774 ms
2023-01-03 22:46:31.734  WARN 2300 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/Jahedullah/ProjectV1/configuration/securityConfiguration/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
2023-01-03 22:46:31.741  INFO 2300 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-01-03 22:46:31.773  INFO 2300 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-03 22:46:31.855 ERROR 2300 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/Jahedullah/ProjectV1/configuration/securityConfiguration/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.Jahedullah.ProjectV1.Tech_Box.main(Tech_Box.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/Jahedullah/ProjectV1/configuration/securityConfiguration/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1573) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1462) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1349) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.beforeConfigure(HttpSecurity.java:3209) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:302) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at com.Jahedullah.ProjectV1.configuration.securityConfiguration.SecurityConfig.filterChain(SecurityConfig.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.Jahedullah.ProjectV1.configuration.securityConfiguration.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c3753457.CGLIB$filterChain$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.Jahedullah.ProjectV1.configuration.securityConfiguration.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c3753457$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f6a04849.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.Jahedullah.ProjectV1.configuration.securityConfiguration.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c3753457.filterChain(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_352]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57041', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this! Because of you the answer was ready and waiting for me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling build at the end, but the object has already been built.  Replace `http.build()` with `http.getOrBuild()`.  This will return the instance with the configurations you've specified if it has already been built, or build it if it hasn't.

Comment: http.GetorBuild makes my code executable. But when i try to login from postman it says 401(Unauthorized). When i debug it never gets into the filter class to authenticate.

Comment: @JahedulIslam That's a separate issue and should have its own question

Comment: This wasn't helpful unfortunately. Same error is occuring

Comment: @GökhanPolat I assume, since you didn't ask the original question, that maybe this answer won't exactly apply to your case?  There could be other causes, please consider asking a question to get the best answer for your case.